# How I can make my Mandelbrot plotter faster?

Tags: python, numpy, plot, turtle-graphics, mandelbrot

How I can make my Python program faster? This program calculates the Mandelbrot set and draws it with turtle. I think the problem is in the for loop. Maybe the steps are taking too much time.

```
import numpy as np
import turtle
turtle.ht()
turtle.pu()
turtle.speed(0)
turtle.delay(0) turtle.colormode(255)

i= int(input("iteration = "))
g = int(input("accuracy  = "))
xmin = float(input("X-min: "))
xmax = float(input("X-max: "))
ymin = float(input("Y-min: "))
ymax = float(input("Y-max: "))
cmode = int(255/i)

input("PRESS TO START")
for x in np.arange(xmin,xmax,1/g):
    for y in np.arange(ymin,ymax,1/g):
        c = x + y * 1j
        z = 0
        t = 1
        for e in range(i):
            z = z * z + c
            if abs(z) > 3:
                turtle.setx(g*c.real)
                turtle.sety(g*c.imag)
                turtle.dot(2,e*cmode,e*cmode,e*cmode)
                t = 0

        if t == 1:
            turtle.setx(g*c.real)
            turtle.sety(g*c.imag)
            turtle.dot(2,"black")

input("Calculated!")
turtle.mainloop()
```

[Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gacT8.png)

Comment: Questions regarding performance are more likely to be answered on the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you! I am a new user here so thanks for your help. Did not know that. @Badda

Comment: First speed-up would be to add `break` following `t = 0` (if the draw routine is triggered, you don't need to continue calculations for this point). Beyond that, Python just isn't terribly fast; you could try to push the calculations into Numpy like https://thesamovar.wordpress.com/2009/03/22/fast-fractals-with-python-and-numpy/ (claims a 3x speed-up) or you could switch to a faster compiled language like Julia https://julialang.org/ (even the name is appropriate ;-) and they include a 20x speed-up on mandelbrot set as one of their benchmarks)

Comment: Do you continue to iterate after the function value has escaped?

Comment: ... one more intermediate step before switching languages: you could try Cython http://cython.org/ which lets you compile (statically typed) Python directly to native code.

Comment: thanks @HughBothwell :)

Comment: @HughBothwell I will take a look at them

Answer (score 1):

The following rework should be a hundred times faster than your original:

```
import numpy as np
import turtle

i = int(input("iteration = "))
g = int(input("accuracy  = "))
xmin = float(input("X-min: "))
xmax = float(input("X-max: "))
ymin = float(input("Y-min: "))
ymax = float(input("Y-max: "))

cmode = int(255 / i)

input("PRESS TO START")

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.penup()
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.colormode(255)
turtle.setundobuffer(None)  # turn off saving undo information

turtle.tracer(0, 0)

for x in np.arange(xmin, xmax, 1 / g):
    for y in np.arange(ymin, ymax, 1 / g):
        c = x + y * 1j
        z = 0
        t = True

        for e in range(i):
            z = z * z + c

            if abs(z) > 3.0:
                turtle.setposition(g * c.real, g * c.imag)
                rgb = e * cmode
                turtle.dot(2, rgb, rgb, rgb)
                t = False
                break

        if t:
            turtle.setposition(g * c.real, g * c.imag)
            turtle.dot(2, "black")

    turtle.update()

print("Calculated!")

turtle.mainloop()
```

The significant change is the use of the combination of `tracer()` and `update()` to avoid visually plotting every dot for the user and just drawing as each vertical column completes.

Comment: Also of major significance is you terminate the iteration when the function value escapes, athough `2.0` is the usual value used - once the function value (magnitude) exceeds that, it never recovers.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I timed a vertical stripe and the `tracer()` / `update()` made about a 20 x improvement and the `break` made about 2 x.  My guess is the `tracer()` improvement is of fixed value whereas the `break` improvement is dependent on the data and could be larger at times.  Also the `break` cleans up some annoying `RuntimeWarning` messages about `cdouble_scalars`.

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you! Its thousand times faster now :)